# Adding Timestamp to excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

This code copies the value from one sheet and past it in another sheet of first empty column, now when I press the button every time I need the following program to work as same in addition to that I need timestamp followed by the copied values.

```
Sub Button2_Click()

Dim source As Worksheet
Dim destination As Worksheet
Dim source1 As Worksheet
Dim destination1 As Worksheet
Dim emptyColumn As Long

Set source = Sheets("Input for Radar")
Set destination = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set source1 = Sheets("Input for Radar")
Set destination1 = Sheets("Sheet2")

If WorksheetFunction.CountA(destination.Columns(1)) Then
    emptyColumn = 1
Else
    emptyColumn = destination.Cells(1, destination.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
End If

destination.Cells(1, emptyColumn).Resize(100, 1).Value = source.Range("s4:s100").Value

If WorksheetFunction.CountA(destination1.Columns(1)) Then
    emptyColumn = 1
Else
    emptyColumn = destination1.Cells(1, destination1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
End If

destination1.Cells(1, emptyColumn).Resize(100, 1).Value = source1.Range("ah4:ah100").Value
```

End Sub

[Please see this example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8XSh.png)

Comment: NOW() is a easy way to get timestamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a function I use for a date-time stamp.

```
Private Function TimeInMS() As String
    Dim TimeNow As Double: TimeNow = Timer
    TimeInMS = Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy ") & Format(DateAdd("s", TimeNow, 0), "hh:mm:ss.") & Right(Format(TimeNow, "#0.00"), 2)
End Function
```